# Find the Rejection Region

Tags: statistics

A drug claims to lower the blood pressure (by at least 10 mmHg) in 30% of all patients. A random sample taken shows a significant drop in blood pressure for only 20% of patients (n =35). Test the original claim using a one-sided test at the 1% significance level.

I was attempting a past paper and this question came up, so i would proceed by stating the null and alternate hypothesis,

Null Hypothesis -> Blood pressure decreases by 30%
Alternate Hypothesis -> Blood Pressure decreases by 20%

For the rejection region,

significance level  = P(Reject Null| Null true)

.01 = P(X > c|Null True)

so c would be 1.28 by looking at the Z table
so the rejection region would be X > 1.28

Im not just to sure about what the conclusion would be?

Comment: I assume you've computed the quotient of the likelihoods? What do you obtain for $c$?

Comment: @Siron so LR = .3/.2 = 1.5 Integrating that from 0 to c, we would get 1.5c = 0.01; c = 2/3. Is that right?

Comment: $20\%$ is the observation, not the alternative hypothesis (or rather, $7$ out of $35$ is the observation)

Comment: @Henry what would my alternate hypothesis be then?

Comment: From the question I would guess the alternative hypothesis is that fewer than $30\%$ of patients see a significant drop in blood pressure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the probability that with a binomial distribution with parameters $n=35, p=0.3$, you observe $0.2\times 35=7$ or fewer successes.

This probability is about $0.13$ (though you might get about $0.1$ if you use a normal approximation without continuity correction), which is rather greater than $0.01$, so you should not reject the null hypothesis.

In R, the calculations might be

```
> pbinom(7, size=35, prob=0.3)                  # exact binomial
[1] 0.1326467
> 
> pnorm(7.5/35, mean=0.3, sd=sqrt(0.3*0.7/35))  # normal with continuity correction
[1] 0.1342407
> 
> pnorm(7/35, mean=0.3, sd=sqrt(0.3*0.7/35))    # normal without continuity correction
[1] 0.0983528
```

Comment: Ahh I get it, i made a mistake reading the question.
So now we find the probability by P(X=1) + P(X=2) .... + P(X=7) = 0.13 > 0.01, hence we don't reject it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, though you should also include $P(X=0)$

Comment: Oh right, Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, this is the answer to what the conclusion would be.  The rejection region would be $4$ successes or fewer out of $35$: calculate $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)$ and see that adding $P(X=5$ would be too much

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't quite understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: I am saying that the *rejection region* is those observations which would have led you to rejecting the null hypothesis.  This is $0,1,2,3,4$ out of $35$, so does not include $7$ out of $35$